# How can I get a table from PL/SQL procedure in Java?

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I have got a package which contains a cursor, a table type on that cursor and a function that returns the table.

```
create or replace package RAPI is
  cursor  coordAndImgCursor  is select latitude, longitude, picture from rapi_buildings;
  type    coordAndImgTable   is table of coordAndImgCursor%rowtype;

  function retreiveCoordsAndImgs( 
    latitude in number, 
    longitude in number, 
    area in number) 
    return coordAndImgTable;
end RAPI;
/
```

Now I am trying to get this table into a Java array, so I need to create a procedure that has an OUT parameter.

```
create or replace procedure jdbc_return(
  latitude IN number, 
  longitude IN number, 
  area IN number, 
  return_table OUT RAPI.coordAndImgTable)
as
begin 
  return_table := RAPI.retreiveCoordsAndImgs(latitude, longitude, area);
end jdbc_return;
/
```

The code is correct and works fine.

Now I have the following Java code:

```
String jdbc_return = "BEGIN 
                        jdbc_return(47.176885, 27.576675, 0.001, ?); 
                      END;";
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(jdbc_return);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cstmt.execute();
```

but I receive this error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'JDBC_RETURN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

How can I get that table from Oracle?

Comment: Can't you just execute and process `select * from table(RAPI.retreiveCoordsAndImgs(?,?,?))` using the usual suspects `PreparedStatement` and  `ResultSet`?

Comment: Well, now I receive `ORA-00902: invalid datatype` error.

Comment: Sorry, apparently that only works for table types that are defined outside of packages...

Comment: Here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/oraarr.htm and here http://betteratoracle.com/posts/26-passing-arrays-between-java-and-oracle-procedures  sql_type have to be OracleTypes.ARRAY. and third parameter sql_type_name  See also here: http://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/24/how-to-retrieve-tables-of-custom-object-types-with-jdbc/